# Docker MariaDB - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected X, found Y. Created with MariaDB 50731, now running 100508

Tags: php, docker, symfony, mariadb, phpstorm

TL;DR: Trying to fix error before it occurs, not when it happens, as in related questions

---

First up: I know the error says to run an upgrade script for the DB.

**However**: I'm running this in Docker. I'm also getting this error after removing the container and the image and creating a new, clean instance.

The database is created by Doctrine, configured for MariaDB 10.5.8 (same version as DB configuration in Docker (see below)).

However, after dumping tables, recreating the db schema and then refreshing the setup in the IDE (PhpStorm) I get this notification:

```
Error encountered when performing Introspect schema workflow_poc: Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 50731, now running 100508. Please use mariadb-upgrade to fix this error.
Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 50731, now running 100508. Please use mariadb-upgrade to fix this error
```

From that I read that the schema was created with a MariaDB 5.7 configuration and now we're running MariaDB 10.5. However, nowhere am I using version 5.7 in this setup.

**Any ideas on how to fix this *before* the error appears and without a hack to include the upgrade command somewhere?**

---

Docker config:

```yaml
db:
  image: library/mariadb:10.5.8
  volumes:
    - "mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql:delegated"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-project_name}
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE:-project_name}
    - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER:-project_name}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-project_name}
    - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
  ports:
    - "${MYSQL_PORT:-30026}:3306"
```

Symfony Doctrine config in `doctrine.yaml`

```yaml
doctrine:
  dbal:
    charset: utf8mb4
    default_table_options:
      charset: utf8mb4
      collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: 'mariadb-10.5.8'
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Comment: Did you try to set the server version directly in the database url/dsn like https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database ?

Comment: I had not, but have now, also does not work. Was under the impression that configuring the version explicitly in the `doctrine.yaml` file would make sure it got added. Tried finding that assumption, but cannot, so good tip, too bad it didn't work.